# ¿Podrían echarme una mano reemplazando un texto con css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

Estoy trabajando sobre esta plantilla en blogger: " https://resaca-maniaca.blogspot.com/ " pero tengo un problema, me gustaría reemplazar el texto "Read more" en las entradas, por "leer más", pero he buscado el texto en la plantilla hasta el hartazgo y no he podido encontrarlo. Me sentiría muy agradecido si alguien me explica como hacerlo. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Tienes el código de la plantilla?

Comment: @JonahFoster por favor edita y genera un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con este código css debería servir, solo lo probé en un navegador (Chrome)

```
.read-more a:before {
    content: 'Leer Más';
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
.read-more a {
    position: relative;
}
```

Lo que se hace con ese código es generar mediante css un pseudo elemento, el cual ponemos sobre el elemento original. Este código ponlo en alguna etiqueta `style` después de las etiquetas `style` de la plantilla.

Postdata: este código lo probé directamente tu blog, usando las herramientas de desarrollo de Chrome.